# How to automatically generate assets/entities from incoming JSON data in Thingsboard?

Tags: json, collections, assets, thingsboard, telemetry

We can successfully download JSON data over the REST-API node which contain many sensors (distinguishable by IDs) of the same type. However, we could not find a possibility to automatically create entities/assets from this collection. The number of sensors is so high that manually adding them would take a lot of time.

Is there a possibility to let these assets be created by a rule chain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to make an external API call to yourself (inside the Rulechain)